# Jest not finding with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Can you tell why this Jest test is failing with ReactJS? I'm trying to test my top level React component `App`:

**ERROR:**
    Runtime Error
      - Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
            at invariant (node_modules/react/node_modules/fbjs/lib/invariant.js:38:15)

**app.js**

```
// ./app.js
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

import Howdy from './app/Howdy';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello 
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**app-test.js**

```
// __tests__/app-test.js

jest.unmock('../app');

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import App from '../app';


describe('Test App Component', () => {

  it('sample test...', () => {
    const myApp = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <App />
    );

    const myAppNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(myApp);

    expect(myAppNode.isElement).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Comment out ReactDOM.render() in app.js.

Comment: But that's my main App module, I guess I can import `App.js` into another .js file that only has a call to `ReactDOM.render()`. I'll try and report the results :-)

Comment: It is customary to import the top level component so there is really nothing to test there. You can still test as straight javascript. Just not with renderIntoDocument.

Comment: OK, commenting out ReactDOM.render() worked. Now I've got to figure out how to test React.DOM.render().

Answer (score 0):

```
const myApp = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
  <App />
```

use `let` instead of `const` in the above block.

> `const` means that the identifier can’t be reassigned. (Not to be confused with immutable values. Unlike true immutable datatypes such as those produced by Immutable.js and Mori, a `const` object can have properties mutated.)
>   If I don’t need to reassign, `const` is my default choice over `let` because I want the usage to be as clear as possible in the code.
>   I use `let` when I need to reassign a variable. Because I use one variable to represent one thing, the use case for `let` tends to be for loops or mathematical algorithms.
>   I don’t use `var` in ES6. There is value in block scope for loops, but I can’t think of a situation where I’d prefer `var` over `let`.

[ref](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75#.5639vgfs4)